# Program to fork 4 child processes and each child will do different operation

Tags: c, linux, process

1. I am given the task of a parent process creating 4 child process and each child process will do addition, subtraction, multiplication and division respectively.
2. I am not able to find the mistake in my code.

Code:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )

{
int i, pid,pid1,pid2,pid3,pid4,num,count;
int status;
if(argc!=3)
    printf("incorrect number of arguments \n");

int A,B,S,T,rem;
num=0;
count=0;
S=0;
T=atoi(argv[2]);
A=atoi(argv[3]);
B=atoi(argv[4]);
printf("%d,\t %d,\t %d \n",T, A, B);
int pid_t;
//////////////////

pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
printf("hi 1 \n");
pid1 = fork();
if (pid1 == 0)
{   pid_t=getpid();
    printf("Forked child %d \n", pid_t);
    fflush(stdout);
    num=(rand() % T);
    sleep(num);
    S=A+B;
    printf("I am child number %d with pid_t %d, the sum is %d \n", count+1, pid_t, S);
    //pid1 code...
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else
    if (pid1 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }

pid2 = fork();
 if (pid2 == 0)
{   pid_t=getpid();
    printf("Forked child %d \n", pid_t);        
//  fflush(stdout);
    num=(rand() % T);
    sleep(num);
    S=A-B;
    printf("I am child number %d with pid_t %d, the difference is %d", count+1, pid_t, S);
        //pid2 code...
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else
    if (pid2 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }

pid3 = fork();
 if (pid3 == 0)
{   pid_t=getpid();
    printf("Forked child %d \n", pid_t);
   // fflush(stdout);
    num=(rand() % T);
    sleep(num);
    S=A*B;
    printf("I am child number %d with pid_t %d, the product is %d", count+1, pid_t, S);
    //pid3 code...
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else
    if (pid3 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }
pid4 = fork();
 if (pid4 == 0)
{   pid_t=getpid();
    printf("Forked child %d \n", pid_t);
  //  fflush(stdout);
    num=(rand() % T);
    sleep(num);
    S=A/B;
    rem=A%B;
    printf("I am child number %d with pid_t %d, the quotient is %d and the remainder is     %d \n", count+1, pid_t, S, rem);
    //pid4 code...
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else
    if (pid4 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }
}
else 
printf("\n no processes ceated \n");

for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
wait(&status);
}
printf("i am done waiting \n");
return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
incorrect number of arguments 
20,      156,      82 
hi 1 
Forked child 14917 
incorrect number of arguments 
20,      156,    82 
hi 1 
Forked child 14978 
incorrect number of arguments 
20,      156,    82 
hi 1 
Forked child 15283
```

Inline Command arguments :

```
main 20 156 82
```

Answer (score 0):

System passes character array with your program name as first argument in `argv`. It will have index `0`. Next `3` parameters you pass, will have indexes 1,2 and 3. So this line

```
 B=atoi(argv[4]);
```

provokes undefined behavior. You should obtain you parameters this way

```
T=atoi(argv[1]);
A=atoi(argv[2]);
B=atoi(argv[3]);
```

There other problems also, but this looks like most significant.

Comment: i did that but i am getting the following output:I am parent process, the maximum sleep time is 0 and the two numbers are 20 and 156

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st fork is unnecessary.
2. you need check divide by zero?
3. you should just use only one wait or each wait_pid(), and better to check return return value.
4. Handle fork faliure?
5. count usage doesn't make any sense.
6. Argument index (argv[1] is missed?)
7. sleep doesn't make any sense to me.
8. coding style

Comment: i am using command line input as :main 20 156 82 so argv[1] is main

Comment: @user3390208 No, in your case, `argv[0]` is `main`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleared up version (to some extend) of the code in original post, I help it may be helpful:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, pid,pid1,pid2,pid3,pid4,count;
    int status;
    if(argc!=3) {
        printf("incorrect number of arguments \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int A,B,S,rem;
    count=0;
    S=0;
    A=atoi(argv[1]);
    B=atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("%d,\t %d\n", A, B);
    //////////////////

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {   
        pid=getpid();
        printf("Forked child %d \n", pid);
        S=A+B;
        printf("I am child number %d with pid %d, the sum is %d \n", count+1, pid, S);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if (pid1 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0)
    {   
        pid=getpid();
        printf("Forked child %d \n", pid);        
        S=A-B;
        printf("I am child number %d with pid %d, the difference is %d \n", count+1, pid, S);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if (pid2 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid3 = fork();
    if (pid3 == 0)
    {   
        pid=getpid();
        printf("Forked child %d \n", pid);
        S=A*B;
        printf("I am child number %d with pid %d, the product is %d \n", count+1, pid, S);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if (pid3 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid4 = fork();
    if (pid4 == 0)
    {   
        pid=getpid();
        printf("Forked child %d \n", pid);
        S=A/B;
        rem=A%B;
        printf("I am child number %d with pid %d, the quotient is %d and the remainder is %d \n", count+1, pid, S, rem);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else if (pid4 < 0)
    {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        wait(&status);
    }

    printf("i am done waiting \n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```